# how to do scatter/gather operations in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

lets say i have arrays:

```
a = array((1,2,3,4,5))
indices = array((1,1,1,1))
```

and i perform operation:

```
a[indices] += 1
```

the result is

```
array([1, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

in other words, the duplicates in `indices` are ignored

if I wanted the duplicates not to be ignored, resulting in:

```
array([1, 6, 3, 4, 5])
```

how would I go about this?

the example above is somewhat trivial, what follows is exactly what I am trying to do:

```
def inflate(self,pressure):
    faceforces = pressure * cross(self.verts[self.faces[:,1]]-self.verts[self.faces[:,0]], self.verts[self.faces[:,2]]-self.verts[self.faces[:,0]])
    self.verts[self.faces[:,0]] += faceforces
    self.verts[self.faces[:,1]] += faceforces
    self.verts[self.faces[:,2]] += faceforces

def constrain_lengths(self):
    vectors = self.verts[self.constraints[:,1]] - self.verts[self.constraints[:,0]]
    lengths = sqrt(sum(square(vectors), axis=1))
    correction = 0.5 * (vectors.T * (1 - (self.restlengths / lengths))).T
    self.verts[self.constraints[:,0]] += correction
    self.verts[self.constraints[:,1]] -= correction

def compute_normals(self):
    facenormals = cross(self.verts[self.faces[:,1]]-self.verts[self.faces[:,0]], self.verts[self.faces[:,2]]-self.verts[self.faces[:,0]])
    self.normals.fill(0)
    self.normals[self.faces[:,0]] += facenormals
    self.normals[self.faces[:,1]] += facenormals
    self.normals[self.faces[:,2]] += facenormals
    lengths = sqrt(sum(square(self.normals), axis=1))
    self.normals = (self.normals.T / lengths).T
```

Ive been getting some very buggy results as a result of duplicates being ignored in my indexed assignment operations.

Answer (score 5):

`numpy`'s `histogram` function is a scatter operation.

`a += histogram(indices, bins=a.size, range=(0, a.size))[0]`

You may need to take some care because if `indices` contains integers, small rounding errors could result in values ending up in the wrong bucket. In which case use:

`a += histogram(indices, bins=a.size, range=(-0.5, a.size-0.5))[0]`

to get each index into the centre of each bin.

Update: this works. But I recommend using @Eelco Hoogendoorn's answer based on `numpy.add.at`.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly late to the party, but seeing how commonly this operation is required, and the fact that it still does not seem to be a part of standard numpy, ill put my solution here for reference:

```
def scatter(rowidx, vals, target):
    """compute target[rowidx] += vals, allowing for repeated values in rowidx"""
    rowidx = np.ravel(rowidx)
    vals   = np.ravel(vals)
    cols   = len(vals)
    data   = np.ones(cols)
    colidx = np.arange(cols)
    rows   = len(target)
    from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
    M = coo_matrix((data,(rowidx,colidx)), shape=(rows, cols))
    target += M*vals
def gather(idx, vals):
    """for symmetry with scatter"""
    return vals[idx]
```

A custom C routine in numpy could easily be twice as fast still, eliminating the superfluous allocation of and multiplication with ones, for starters, but it makes a world of difference in performance versus a loop in python.

Aside from performance considerations, it is stylistically much more in line with other numpy-vectorized code to use a scatter operation, rather than mash some for loops in your code.

Edit:

Ok, forget about the above. As of the lastest 1.8 release, doing scatter operations is now directly supported in numpy at optimal efficiency.

```
def scatter(idx, vals, target):
    """target[idx] += vals, but allowing for repeats in idx"""
    np.add.at(target, idx.ravel(), vals.ravel())
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it that is any faster than:

```
for face in self.faces[:,0]:
    self.verts[face] += faceforces
```

You could also make self.faces into an array of 3 dictionaries where the keys correspond to the face and the value to the number of times it needs to be added. You'd then get code like:

```
for face in self.faces[0]:
    self.verts[face] += self.faces[0][face]*faceforces
```

which might be faster. I do hope that someone comes up with a better way because I wanted to do this when trying to help someone speed-up their code earlier today.