# Find two disjoint pairs of pairs that sum to the same vector

Tags: python, numpy

This is a follow-up to [Find two pairs of pairs that sum to the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124061/find-two-pairs-of-pairs-that-sum-to-the-same-value) .

I have random 2d arrays which I make using

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
n = 50
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(m,n))
```

I would like to determine if the matrix has two disjoint pairs of pairs of columns which sum to the same column vector. I am looking for a fast method to do this. In the previous problem ((0,1), (0,2)) was acceptable as a pair of pairs of column indices but in this case it is not as 0 is in both pairs.

The accepted answer from the previous question is so cleverly optimised I can't see how to make this simple looking change unfortunately.  (I am interested in columns rather than rows in this question but I can always just do A.transpose().)

Here is some code to show it testing all 4 by 4 arrays.

```
n = 4
nxn = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, -1)
count = 0
for i in xrange(2**(n*n)):
   A = (i >> nxn) %2
   p = 1
   for firstpair in combinations(range(n), 2):
       for secondpair in combinations(range(n), 2):
           if firstpair < secondpair and not set(firstpair) & set(secondpair):
              if (np.array_equal(A[firstpair[0]] + A[firstpair[1]], A[secondpair[0]] + A[secondpair[1]] )):
                  if (p):
                      count +=1
                      p = 0
print count
```

This should output 3136.

Comment: What's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, extended to do what I believe you want. It isn't entirely clear though; one may get an arbitrary number of row-pairs that sum to the same total; there may exist unique subsets of rows within them that sum to the same value. For instance:

Given this set of row-pairs that sum to the same total

```
[[19 19 30 30]
 [11 16 11 16]]
```

There exists a unique subset of these rows that may still be counted as valid; but should it?

```
[[19 30]
 [16 11]]
```

Anyway, I hope those details are easy to deal with, given the code below.

```
import numpy as np

n = 20
#also works for non-square A
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(n*6,n)).astype(np.int8)
##A = np.array( [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1 ,1]], np.uint8)
##A = np.zeros((6,6))
#force the inclusion of some hits, to keep our algorithm on its toes
##A[0] = A[1]


def base_pack_lazy(a, base, dtype=np.uint64):
    """
    pack the last axis of an array as minimal base representation
    lazily yields packed columns of the original matrix
    """
    a = np.ascontiguousarray( np.rollaxis(a, -1))
    packing = int(np.dtype(dtype).itemsize * 8 / (float(base) / 2))
    for columns in np.array_split(a, (len(a)-1)//packing+1):
        R = np.zeros(a.shape[1:], dtype)
        for col in columns:
            R *= base
            R += col
        yield R

def unique_count(a):
    """returns counts of unique elements"""
    unique, inverse = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    count = np.zeros(len(unique), np.int)
    np.add.at(count, inverse, 1)        #note; this scatter operation requires numpy 1.8; use a sparse matrix otherwise!
    return unique, count, inverse

def voidview(arr):
    """view the last axis of an array as a void object. can be used as a faster form of lexsort"""
    return np.ascontiguousarray(arr).view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[-1]))).reshape(arr.shape[:-1])


def has_identical_row_sums_lazy(A, combinations_index):
    """
    compute the existence of combinations of rows summing to the same vector,
    given an nxm matrix A and an index matrix specifying all combinations

    naively, we need to compute the sum of each row combination at least once, giving n^3 computations
    however, this isnt strictly required; we can lazily consider the columns, giving an early exit opportunity
    all nicely vectorized of course
    """

    multiplicity, combinations = combinations_index.shape
    #list of indices into combinations_index, denoting possibly interacting combinations
    active_combinations = np.arange(combinations, dtype=np.uint32)
    #keep all packed columns; we might need them later
    columns = []

    for packed_column in base_pack_lazy(A, base=multiplicity+1):       #loop over packed cols
        columns.append(packed_column)
        #compute rowsums only for a fixed number of columns at a time.
        #this is O(n^2) rather than O(n^3), and after considering the first column,
        #we can typically already exclude almost all combinations
        partial_rowsums = sum(packed_column[I[active_combinations]] for I in combinations_index)
        #find duplicates in this column
        unique, count, inverse = unique_count(partial_rowsums)
        #prune those combinations which we can exclude as having different sums, based on columns inspected thus far
        active_combinations = active_combinations[count[inverse] > 1]
        #early exit; no pairs
        if len(active_combinations)==0:
            return False

    """
    we now have a small set of relevant combinations, but we have lost the details of their particulars
    to see which combinations of rows does sum to the same value, we do need to consider rows as a whole
    we can simply apply the same mechanism, but for all columns at the same time,
    but only for the selected subset of row combinations known to be relevant
    """
    #construct full packed matrix
    B = np.ascontiguousarray(np.vstack(columns).T)
    #perform all relevant sums, over all columns
    rowsums = sum(B[I[active_combinations]] for I in combinations_index)
    #find the unique rowsums, by viewing rows as a void object
    unique, count, inverse = unique_count(voidview(rowsums))
    #if not, we did something wrong in deciding on active combinations
    assert(np.all(count>1))

    #loop over all sets of rows that sum to an identical unique value
    for i in xrange(len(unique)):
        #set of indexes into combinations_index;
        #note that there may be more than two combinations that sum to the same value; we grab them all here
        combinations_group = active_combinations[inverse==i]
        #associated row-combinations
        #array of shape=(mulitplicity,group_size)
        row_combinations = combinations_index[:,combinations_group]

        #if no duplicate rows involved, we have a match
        if len(np.unique(row_combinations[:,[0,-1]])) == multiplicity*2:
            print row_combinations
            return True

    #none of identical rowsums met uniqueness criteria
    return False


def has_identical_triple_row_sums(A):
    n = len(A)
    idx = np.array( [(i,j,k)
        for i in xrange(n)
            for j in xrange(n)
                for k in xrange(n)
                    if i<j and j<k], dtype=np.uint16)
    idx = np.ascontiguousarray( idx.T)
    return has_identical_row_sums_lazy(A, idx)

def has_identical_double_row_sums(A):
    n = len(A)
    idx = np.array(np.tril_indices(n,-1), dtype=np.int32)
    return has_identical_row_sums_lazy(A, idx)


from time import clock
t = clock()
for i in xrange(1):
##    print has_identical_double_row_sums(A)
    print has_identical_triple_row_sums(A)
print clock()-t
```

Edit: code cleanup

Comment: In the case of a 2 by 4 array [[19 19 30 30], [11 16 11 16]]  columns 0 and 3 have the same sum as columns 1 and 2.  It doesn't make sense to consider rows for this problem as you need at least 4 for the definition of my problem to work.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Indeed, the sum over all indices in each of the 4 columns gives the same total. It would appear to me however, that the 2x2 subset [[19 30] [16 11]] meets the definition of combinations you are interested in, no?

Comment: Sorry there must be a misunderstanding. We need to find two disjoint pairs of pairs of columns. Say we find columns 0 and 1 in one set and 2 and 3 in the other. We then do the vector sum for columns 0 and 1 and get the vector [39,27] in this case. We then do the same for columns 2 and 3 and get [60,27] and find that [39,27] != [60,27]. However had we chosen  columns 0 and 3 and columns 1 and 2 we would have got [49,27] for both vectors which is what we wanted to find.  If there are only 2 columns we can't get two disjoint subsets of size 2 each.

Comment: The tables I wrote down contains the indices into A. It is presumed that A has only 0 and 1 values in this code; so the vector sum can only be something like [2,1,0], not [39,27]. Indeed there seems to be a substantial misunderstanding between us. Have you tried running the code and looking at the output?

Comment: It should only have 0s and 1s as you say. I was just using the example you gave in your answer but I see I misunderstood completely what was in it! Let me run your code and take a look.

Comment: OK I ran the code with this example A= [[0 0 0], [1 1 1],  [1 1 1]] . In this case there don't exist two disjoint pairs of pairs of rows so the code should just report an invalid sized input (or False). Can you explain what the output the code gives [[1 2], [0 0]] means? Is it saying that row 1 plus row 0 equals row 2 plus row 0?

Comment: However, a 4 by 4 all zeros matrix should return True so I am not sure how to modify your code now.

Comment: Exactly; that is what [[1 2], [0 0]] means. As the output notes, you are not interested in this guy. For an all-zeros matrix, you get a 2x6 matrix denoting all possible sums of pairs that sum to the zero vector. Again, the code notes that set of combinations is not unique; but it  does have a unique subset, namely [[2 3], [0 1]], which as you just revealed, you do consider a valid combination. Note that [[1 2], [0 0]] does not have a unique subset; we cant remove anything from it so that we only have one zero, and still have a pair of pairs.

Comment: Great, we have converged :)  I definitely do want to return True when there is a unique subset as you say.

Comment: One could simply perform a brute-force search over all possible combinations of columns of such a matrix, and see if they form a unique subset. However, the maximum size of such a set is of O(n^2), for instance for an all-zero matrix, so running an O(n^2) algorithm on that may not be the best idea. But if your actual data stays well clear of such corner cases, brute force should be fine for these typically tiny arrays.

Comment: Wait a sec; there may be a shortcut. The indices appear sorted, first by the top row, then by the bottom row. Moreover, the first value is always the bigger one. If the first and last column don't form a unique subset, I don't think any combination does. Don't quote me on that yet, though...

Comment: I got your code to work using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146721/find-a-pair-of-pairs-with-no-intersection . However your code is much slower than the naive code I have in my question. About 15 seconds versus 4 seconds. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I edited the code to include a check for unique pairs. Note sure about the performance differences. To keep my algorithm busy for 15 seconds on my computer, I need 1000's of entries when checking for double sums, and 100's when checking for triple sums. Are you testing your naïve algorithm with the same parameters? By comparison; your naïve algo also takes about 4 seconds on my computer; for n=4... try your naïve algo with n=10000; I think the universe might have undergone heat death by the time it returns ;)

Comment: Thanks. I get 15 seconds when I have it in the loop in my question which iterates over all 4 by 4 matrices.  Maybe it is particularly slow for small n?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense; for n close to one, the overhead of all the tricks going on to make it scale well to larger n certainly isn't going to pay off; for those small n, a factor 4 slower than brute force does not surprise me.