# Find a pair of pairs with no intersection

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Given a set of n pairs of integers, is there a fast way to determine if there exists two pairs (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) so that the intersection of the sets {x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>} and {x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>} is empty?

For example, {(0,1), (0,2), (2,1), (3,2)} has {(0,1), (3,2)} as an answer. However {(0,1), (0,2), (2,1)} has no such pair of pairs.

In Python, you could just try all pairs as follows.

```
l = [(0,1), (0,2), (2,1), (3,2)]
print  [pairs for pairs in itertools.combinations(l, 2)
    if not (set(pairs[0]) & set(pairs[1]))]
```

This approach takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. Can you get something closer to linear time?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask in [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bakuriu There is definitely an overlap but I really need code so stackoverflow seems suitable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Before reading this *read* [templatetypedef answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21147214/510937).

<sup>I'll personally hunt whoever upvotes this answer without upvoting his answer, since *he* did all the work</sup>

---

Here's a (self-explanatory) python implementation of the algorithm defined in [templatetypedef answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21147214/510937):

```
def exists_pair(seq):
    if len(seq) < 2:
        return False
    a, b = seq[0]  # could be: seq.pop() if modifications are allowed
    a_group = set()
    b_group = set()
    for c, d in seq:
        if not ({a,b} & {c,d}):
            return True
        elif {a,b} == {c,d}:
            continue
        elif a in {c,d}:
            a_group.add(c if c != a else d)
        else:
            b_group.add(c if c != b else d)

    if not a_group:
        return False

    # b_group - a_group: elements of b_group that do not appear in a_group
    return bool(b_group - a_group)
```

There's no need to check for an empty `b_group` because the result of `b_group - a_group` is always a subset of `b_group`. If `b_group` is empty the result will always be empty and `bool` of empty `set` is `False`, which is correct.

Comment: If seq = [[2,0], [3,0]] the output should be False but this code gives True.

Comment: @marshall I *might* have fixed it. The problem with that input is that, when building the A-group we don't find any pair that matches. Thus at the end the code checks with `3` is in the A-group, which is true since it's empty, and assume there exist a pair. But we can say this only if the A-group isn't empty.

Answer (score 5):

The following algorithm should work in O(n) time. It's based on the following observation: if you have a pair {a, b}, then every other pair

1. Doesn't include a or b, or
2. Includes at least one of a or b.

If you choose any set {a, b} and categorize each other set into one of these five categories, note that if you get anything in Case 1, then you're done and you know such a pair exists. So the only interesting case is when every other set falls into case 2. When this happens, we can call the two groups the "A" group and the "B" group (for sets that match a and for sets that match b).

Once you have the A group and the B group, you know that no two A sets can be the pair you want, no two B sets can be the pair you want, and the set {a, b} can't be part of the pair you want. The only option is if you can take something from the A group and pair it with something from the B group. This only happens if some non-A component from the A group doesn't match any non-B component from the B group. You can check this in O(n) by building a hash table holding the non-A components of the A group and then checking for each element of the B group whether its non-B component is in the hash set.

To summarize, the algorithm is

- Choose a pair {a, b}.
- For each other pair {c, d}:

  - If {a, b} and {c, d} are disjoint, you're done.
  - Otherwise, if {a, b} = {c, d}, discard {c, d}.
  - Otherwise, put {c, d} into either the A group if it includes a or the B group if it includes b.
- If either the A group or B group is empty, no pair exists. Return false.
- For each element of the A group, add the non-a component of the pair to a hash set.
- Return true if any element of the B group has a non-b component not in the hash set and false otherwise.

This runs in time O(n) and uses O(n) extra memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, it's trivial to show an O(nlogn) in-place algorithm, based on the above. Instead of building an hash set you can store the A group at the beginning of the list and the B group at the end. Then you can sort the A group by the non-a element and the B-group by the non-b element, scan one of the two and use bisection search on the other. Sure, handling correctly the indexes to avoid overlaps and correct sorting/scanning would make the code probably ugly...

Comment: @Bakuriu That sounds good too. Remember that given that I need to implement it in python, nothing is trivial :)